# Unlocking Android phone immediately after reboot

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, sim-unlocking, oneplus-one

I have an Android phone (version 5.1.1) with cyanogenmod (version 12.1). And after rebooting I cannot immediately unlock my phone. If I try to unlock my screen (lock style = pattern) immediately after rebooting I always get the message: "try again in x seconds" where x is counting down from 30 to 0. I find this very annoying,  is there any way to disable this?

Edit: I just found out that I can actually unlock my screen before it asks me to enter my pin for unlocking my sim card. But when I do this it locks again as soon as it a asks me to enter my pin for unlocking my sim, and again have to wait 30 sec.

Comment: Are you using a Nightly build?

Comment: I have the version of CyanogenMod that comes preinstalled on the one plus. I also had this problem before the most recent system update. I doubt that one plus installes unreleased versions of CyanogenMod automatically, so it is probably not a nightly build.

Comment: I had this problem, and it kind of just.... Went.

Comment: @Manubhargav thats what exactly started this for me. I'd turn it on, and whilst boot i would make a cuppa. when I get back, the screen is off. wake it, the countdown starts.

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* This is a workaround.

Some users have posted about the bug (saying this bug is present from long time)
 in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/3jcsxy/try_again_in_30_seconds_every_boot/) and [oneplus forums](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/lock-screen-pattern-not-working-for-the-first-time.288592/).
Since it is a bug, there is no definitive solution to this.

One possible work around is to simply turn off the screen by pressing  <kbd>lock button</kbd>
and turn back on by pressing  <kbd>lock button</kbd>  again, and enter your pattern.

Comment: I just tried this workaround, but it doesn't work for me. After turning my screen off and on again the countdown just continues.

Comment: It has worked for some people. Also this is, not just confined to oneplus one, bug's been present in [Samsung phones from 3 years](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1584624)

Comment: @koffie Bug reported across Fairphone forums [here](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/try-again-in-x-seconds-when-turning-on-fp/5787) and [here](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/screen-turns-black-after-i-enter-a-wrong-unlock-pattern-bluescreen-at-startup/5859), Maybe a 3rd party app is causing the issue, Try booting in [safe mode](http://www.androidexplained.com/boot-oneplus-one-safe-mode/) and see if the issue is gone, If so, then, an installed app is causing the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing a factory reset.
If it doesn't fix that way it must be addressed to oneplus and patched by them or installing a custom CyanogenMod where the bug is fixed.

Comment: Is there a confirmation that the Cyanogenmod builds doesn't have this issue? If yes, then please confirm. If not but there is a bug filed already then provide a link please.

Comment: @Firelord I can confirm they DO NOT fix this. For me, these only started when in installed CM.